# How print this in View? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have following action in my Controlle

```
public ViewResult CreateCollection() 
    { 
        string[] stringArray = { "apple", "orange", "plum" }; 
        List<int> intList = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 40 }; 
        Dictionary<string, int> myDict = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "apple", 10 }, { "orange", 20 }, { "plum", 30 } };
        return View("Result", (object)stringArray[1]);
    }
```

So when i want to print out "orange"
i use this View:

```
    @model String
@{    Layout = null; } 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />    
    <title>Result</title> 
</head> 
<body>    
    <div>        
    @Model    
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

If I want to print out "20", seconde number from intList
I change in View @model String to @model int and in action I change return parametar stringArray to intList.

But I don't know how to print something from myDict, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dedicated view model

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public Dictionary<string, int> Fruits {get; set;}
   public string SelectedFruit {get; set;}
}
```

Change controller action so it returns a view with an instance of your new `ViewModel`

```
public ActionResult CreateCollection() 
    { 
        string[] stringArray = { "apple", "orange", "plum" }; 
        List<int> intList = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 40 }; 
        Dictionary<string, int> myDict = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "apple", 10 }, { "orange", 20 }, { "plum", 30 } };
        var model = new ViewModel
        {
             SelectedFruit = stringArray[1],
             Fruits = myDict 
        }
        return View("Result", model );
    }
```

Change your view to get a `ViewModel` as a model:

```
@model LanguageFeatures.Models.ViewModel
@{    Layout = null; } 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />    
    <title>Result</title> 
</head> 
<body>    
    <div>        
    Selected Fruit: @Model.SelectedFruit 
    </div> 
    <div>        
    Quantity: @Model.Fruits[Model.SelectedFruit]  
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

The bottom line that all the information that you want to use inside your view has to be part of the model (you can use ViewBag, Session, ViewData but it is less preferred way of passing data to the view) and controller is the one that is responsible for instantiating this model

Comment: Huh, its much more complicated then I expected, but i did what u sad. And get this error -> http://prntscr.com/9qhi1y... And here is how i made dedicated view model -> http://prntscr.com/9qhj20

Comment: First line of View i changed to this : @model LanguageFeatures.Models.ViewModel and it works. Thx for your help.